# Como importar fuentes de un archivo local, a mi proyecto HTML

Tags: css, fuentes

Tengo un problema y la verdad no doy con mi solución. Tengo unos archivos otf, que son unas fuentes que me ha pasado un diseñador. Las estoy importando de la siguiente forma:

```
        @font-face {
            font-family: Verlag;
            src: url('/wp-content/themes/raisedRealTheme/fonts/Verlag-Black.otf'), 
                 url('/wp-content/themes/raisedRealTheme/fonts/Verlag-Bold.otf'), 
                 url('/wp-content/themes/raisedRealTheme/fonts/Verlag-Bold.otf'),
                 url('/wp-content/themes/raisedRealTheme/fonts/Verlag-Book.otf'), 
                 url('/wp-content/themes/raisedRealTheme/fonts/Verlag-Light.otf'),
                 url('/wp-content/themes/raisedRealTheme/fonts/Verlag-XLight.otf');
        }

        body
        {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 900;
            font-family: Verlag;
        }
```

Pero en mi HTML no veo que se esta cargando,porque me esta saltando un error de

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Pero si le doy click al link del browser, puedo ver la fuente. Acá dejo una imagen de mi path, para ver que estoy fallando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

P.D: Es un proyecto wordpress.

Comment: prueba de cambiarlo a `../fonts/Verlag-XLight.otf`

Comment: Tendría que ser ../fonts

Comment: @aldanux Si ahorita lo vi, y era eso....Lo que pasa es que Wordpress me hace pasadas en momentos desde el HTML necesita el wp-contetn...... y para otras no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luego de publicar la pregunta, me di cuenta que que era de esta forma:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Verlag;
    src: url('../fonts/Verlag-Black.otf'), url('../fonts/Verlag-Bold.otf'), url('../fonts/Verlag-Bold.otf'),
    url('../fonts/Verlag-Book.otf'), url('../fonts/Verlag-Light.otf'),
    url('../fonts/Verlag-XLight.otf');
}
```

Como coloque en el comentario, Wordpress hay momento que necesita el `wp-content/..../....` y para este caso no es necesario.